# Launch a .reg file from NSIS

Tags: registry, nsis

I would like to know how to launch a .reg file using NSIS.

this file looks like this:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DriverSearching]
"SearchOrderConfig"=dword:00000003

thanks in advance!
Bye

Comment: WriteRegDWORD HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DriverSearching" "SearchOrderConfig" 0x00000003

Comment: but it wasn't successful

Answer (score 1):

```
WriteRegDWORD HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DriverSearching" "SearchOrderConfig" 0x00000003
```

There are two things issues you need to deal with for this to work:

1. Only administrators can write to HKLM so you need to add `RequestExecutionLevel admin` to your script.
2. On 64-bit versions of Windows this is going to write to the 32-bit view of the registry so you probably want to call `SetRegView 64` before `WriteRegDWORD`.

It can be helpful to use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to see why a registry write fails and to verify that you are writing to the correct place.

Comment: Thank You so Much! It's ok!

Comment: @P.Martin No need to comment, just mark it as the answer if it worked.

Comment: I see you're just taking the code from the .reg file and converted it to an NSIS command. Can the .reg file itself just be run using ExecWait?

Comment: @KyleDelaney You can do that but you lose control of the 32/64 bit views on 64-bit Windows.